# Replace Flash Notice with Bootstrap Modal in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, flash, bootstrap-modal

So I have a page where a user clicks a button and this posts a form and uploads a pdf file in the background. Upon completion of posting the form, a flash notice appears saying the pdf has successfully been uploaded. I'd like to show a modal instead of a flash notice when the background pdf upload is complete. How can I do that?

`pages_controller.rb`

```
def send_pdf
  require "net/http"
  uri = URI('http://www.skillchest.com/users/receive_certificate')
  x = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)
  puts x.body
  redirect_to pages_course_page_certificate_path, notice: 'You have sent your pdf to <u><a href=http://www.website>website</a></u>. Login now to check it out!'.html_safe
  ## how to make the above line show as a modal instead of a flash notice?
end
```

`course_page_certificate.html.erb`

```
<h1>Congratulations! Here is your certificate.</h1>
<%= form_tag({controller: "pages", action: "send_pdf"}, method: "post") %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:end_date, @today) %>
<% url = current_user.certificate.s3_object.url_for(:read, :expires => 10*60) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:pdf_url, url) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:student_email, current_user.email) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:institution_id, '2') %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:course_title, 'Lesson 1') %>
<%= submit_tag "Send Your Certificate to SkillChest", class: "btn btn-warning btn-lg continue" %>
```

When the user clicks the "Send your Certificate" button, the certificate is posted to a url in the controller action. Then the notice appears says it was succesffully sent. All this works fine, I just would like to show a modal on completion of the http post action rather than a flash notice. How would I do this?

Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't a perfect answer, as the notice is still there, but here's what I did to get the modal working.

I just checked for if the `alert` class html contained the notice message. If it does, then I show the modal that I want.  Of course ideally I would only show the modal and not the notice, but still haven't figured that part out yet.

```
if ($(".alert").html().indexOf("You have sent your") >= 0) {
  $("#sendToSkillChestModal").modal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check out the documentation for [the Flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash).

For your case, you can change the flash to be custom so it would not show as a notice.

```
def send_pdf
  require "net/http"
  uri = URI('http://www.skillchest.com/users/receive_certificate')
  x = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)
  puts x.body
  redirect_to pages_course_page_certificate_path, flash[:pdf_upload] = 'You have sent your pdf'
  ## will use :pdf_upload in view
end
```

Then in your view you can put something like:

```
<% if flash[:pdf_upload] %>
  <%= render 'pdf_upload_modal.html' %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can put anything you like in the partial '_pdf_upload_modal.html' and use Jquery to fadeout the partial.

This is not a true modal, but it worked well for me.  Hope this helps!